# Header include not working

Tags: php, header, include

SO i have a page, and the header is like this:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"></div>
 <div id="menubar">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="select_cafes.php">Cafés</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="select_cafes_murtosa.php">Murtosa</a></li>
                <li><a href="select_cafes_torreira.php">Torreira</a></li>
                <li><a href="select_cafes_monte.php">Monte</a></li>
                <li><a href="select_cafes_bunheiro.php">Bunheiro</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="select_restaurantes.php">Restaurantes</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="select_restaurantes_murtosa.php">Murtosa</a></li>
                <li><a href="select_restaurantes_torreira.php">Torreira</a></li>
                <li><a href="select_restaurantes_monte.php">Monte</a></li>
                <li><a href="select_restaurantes_bunheiro.php">Bunheiro</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="select_alojamentos.php">Alojamento</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="select_turismorural.php">Turismo Rural</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="select_turismorural_murtosa.php">Murtosa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="select_turismorural_torreira.php">Torreira</a></li>
                    <li><a href="select_turismorural_monte.php">Monte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="select_turismorural_bunheiro.php">Bunheiro</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="select_hoteis.php">Hotéis</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="select_hoteis_murtosa.php">Murtosa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="select_hoteis_torreira.php">Torreira</a></li>
                    <li><a href="select_hoteis_monte.php">Monte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="select_hoteis_bunheiro.php">Bunheiro</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="select_pensoes.php">Pensões</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="select_pensoes_murtosa.php">Murtosa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="select_pensoes_torreira.php">Torreira</a></li>
                    <li><a href="select_pensoes_monte.php">Monte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="select_pensoes_bunheiro.php">Bunheiro</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="select_edificios.php">Edificios Municipais</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="select_edificios_murtosa.php">Murtosa</a></li>
                <li><a href="select_edificios_torreira.php">Torreira</a></li>
                <li><a href="select_edificios_monte.php">Monte</a></li>
                <li><a href="select_edificios_bunheiro.php">Bunheiro</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contato.php">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

I dotn want to repeat this on every single page, so i tried to put that code in a file named header.php. And on index.php i removed that code and used `<?php include(header.php);?>`

And it dont work.. Can somebody help me?

Comment: How didn't it work? Errors?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot quotes - `<?php include("header.php");?>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the included file (`header.php`) between quotes.

```
<?php include('header.php');?>
```

Otherwise, you will got an error. Like in this case.